# websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason

Tags: python, websocket

- I am trying to receive data from a website which use websocket. This acts like this:
  [websocket handshaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW6uk.png)

Here is the code to catch data:

```
async def hello(symb_id: int):
    async with websockets.connect("wss://ws.bitpin.ir/", extra_headers = request_header, timeout=15) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('{"method":"sub_to_price_info"}')
        recv_msg = await websocket.recv()
        if recv_msg == '{"message": "sub to price info"}':
            await websocket.send(json.dumps({"method":"sub_to_market","id":symb_id}))
            recv_msg = await websocket.recv()
            counter = 1 

            while(1):
                msg = await websocket.recv()
                print(counter, msg[:100], end='\n\n')
                counter+=1

asyncio.run(hello(1))
```

- After receiving about 100 message, I am facing with this error:

```
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

- I tried to set `timeout` and `request headers` but these were not helpful

Comment: I am suspecting to `PING` message which is shown in the picture. Does `websockets ` module send this message automatically?

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this error by creating a task for sending `PING`.

```
async def hello(symb_id: int):
    async with websockets.connect("wss://ws.bitpin.ir/", extra_headers = request_header, timeout=10, ping_interval=None) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('{"method":"sub_to_price_info"}')
        recv_msg = await websocket.recv()
        if recv_msg == '{"message": "sub to price info"}':
            await websocket.send(json.dumps({"method":"sub_to_market","id":symb_id}))
            recv_msg = await websocket.recv()
            counter = 1 

            task = asyncio.create_task(ping(websocket))
            while True:
                msg = await websocket.recv()
                await return_func(msg)
                print(counter, msg[:100], end='\n\n')
                counter+=1


async def ping(websocket):
    while True:
        await websocket.send('{"message":"PING"}')
        print('------ ping')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK` exception can get thrown when you send a message to a WebSocket that is in the middle of closing.

Because the client can close the socket whenever it wants, this can happen at any time and with async code the chances of this happening is pretty decent if you both send frequently and clients come and go frequently.

You can catch `ConnectionClosedOK` to handle this:

```py
from WebSocket.exceptions import ConnectionClosedOK

try:
    await websocket.send(json.dumps({"method":"sub_to_market","id":symb_id}))
except ConnectionClosedOK:
    # ...
```

Depending on your use case you may want to catch its [parent exception](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/exceptions.html#websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed), `ConnectionClosed`, instead as this will handle both expected and unexpected closure states.