# FastAPI - Websockets, Multiple connections for one client

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, fastapi

Trying to implement websockets in my fastapi application, however, when I connect to the websocket from the javascript side, it opens 4 connections, I have implemented a workaround in the backend side that check if the certain customer is connected, however this would mean that a client couldn't connect to the websocket on mobile while it's open on the computer for example.

```py
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections: dict[int, WebSocket] = {}

    async def connect(self, websocket, customer_id):
        existing_connection = self.connections.get(customer_id)
        if existing_connection:
            await websocket.close()
            raise ExistingConnectionError("Existing connection for customer_id")

        await websocket.accept()
        websocket.customer_id = customer_id
        self.connections[customer_id] = websocket
        print(list(self.connections.values()))

    async def disconnect(self, websocket):
        customer_id = getattr(websocket, 'customer_id', None)
        if customer_id in self.connections:
            del self.connections[customer_id]

    async def broadcast(self, message):
        for websocket in self.connections.values():
            await websocket.send_json(message)

    async def broadcast_to_customer(self, customer_id, message):
        matching_connection = self.connections.get(customer_id)
        if matching_connection:
            await matching_connection.send_json(message)


connection_manager = ConnectionManager()
```

```py
@router.websocket("/sock")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, customer_id: int):
    try:
        await connection_manager.connect(websocket, customer_id)
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await connection_manager.disconnect(websocket)
    except ExistingConnectionError:
        print("Existing connection detected, rejecting the new connection")
```

Javascript:

```js
let socket;

    if (!socket || socket.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
        socket = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:3002/sock?customer_id=${customer_id}`);

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Connected to WebSocket server');
        };

        let i = 0;

        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log('Incoming data:', data);
            console.log('i:', i);
            i = i + 1;
        };
    }
```

Backend logs:

```
INFO:     connection open
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 33366) - "WebSocket /sock?customer_id=185" 403
Existing connection detected, rejecting the new connection
INFO:     connection rejected (403 Forbidden)
INFO:     connection closed
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 33368) - "WebSocket /sock?customer_id=185" 403
Existing connection detected, rejecting the new connection
INFO:     connection rejected (403 Forbidden)
INFO:     connection closed
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 33384) - "WebSocket /sock?customer_id=185" 403
Existing connection detected, rejecting the new connection
INFO:     connection rejected (403 Forbidden)
INFO:     connection closed
```

Frontend logs:

```
Connected to WebSocket server
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3002/sock?customer_id=185.
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3002/sock?customer_id=185.
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3002/sock?customer_id=185.
```

Tried to implement websocket in FastAPI, opens multiple connections instead of one, for each client.

Comment: Please have a look at the following answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

On the backend store connections for every device of every client:

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients: dict[int, dict[str, WebSocket]] = {}

    async def connect(self, websocket, customer_id, device_hash):
        client_connections = self.clients.get(customer_id)
        if client_connections:
            client_device_connection = client_connections.get(device_hash)
            if client_device_connection:
                await websocket.close()
                raise ExistingConnectionError("Existing connection for customer_id")
        else:
            self.clients[customer_id] = {}

        await websocket.accept()
        websocket.customer_id = customer_id
        websocket.device_hash = device_hash

        self.clients[customer_id][device_hash] = websocket
        print(list(self.clients.values()))

    async def disconnect(self, websocket):
        customer_id = getattr(websocket, 'customer_id', None)
        device_hash = getattr(websocket, 'device_hash', None)
        client_connections = self.clients.get(customer_id)
        if client_connections:
            if client_connections.get(device_hash):
                client_connections.pop(device_hash)

    async def broadcast(self, message):
        for client_connections in self.clients.values():
            for websocket in client_connections.values():
                await websocket.send_json(message)

    async def broadcast_to_customer(self, customer_id, message):
        client_connections = self.client.get(customer_id)
        if client_connections:
            for connection in client_connections.values():
                await connection.send_json(message)


connection_manager = ConnectionManager()

@app.websocket("/sock")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, customer_id: int, device_hash: str):

    try:
        await connection_manager.connect(websocket, customer_id, device_hash)
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await connection_manager.disconnect(websocket)
    except ExistingConnectionError:
        print("Existing connection detected, rejecting the new connection")
```

When you connect to websocket from frontend, add additional query parameter `device_hash`, which should be unique for every user device.
You can also generate this `device_hash` on the server side from request headers (e.g. you can use `user-agent`)

Comment: This seems to be a nice solution, thanks. However, do you think my connection logic is correct? Or is it normal for it to open four connections? I am not sure if i am connecting to the websocket correctly in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to how you are checking for an existing WebSocket connection on the frontend.

In your JavaScript code, you are creating a new WebSocket connection every time without checking if a connection already exists. To ensure that only one WebSocket connection is established, you should handle the WebSocket creation logic differently. One approach is to create a WebSocket only if it doesn't exist or if it is not in the open state.
example modification to your JavaScript code:

```
let socket;

// Check if the socket is undefined or not open
if (!socket || socket.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
    // Create a new WebSocket connection
    socket = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:3002/sock?customer_id=${customer_id}`);

    socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Connected to WebSocket server');
    };

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('Incoming data:', data);
    };

    socket.onclose = (event) => {
        console.log('WebSocket closed:', event);
    };
}
```

This modification ensures that a new WebSocket connection is created only if there isn't an existing connection or if the existing connection is not in the open state.

You may want to handle the onclose event to handle cases where the WebSocket connection is closed unexpectedly.

Comment: What "modification" did you actually do? Your check for and existing WebSocket connection is exactly the same as OP's. And you even claim he doesn't have that check.

Comment: @gre_gor He copied and pasted the ChatGPT answer.

Comment: @Abrskil Yes, I am suspecting that, since they posted multiple nonsensical answers.