# websockets : ConnectionClosedOK: received 1000 (OK); then sent 1000 (OK)

Tags: python

I'm trying to exchange data between 2 processes using websockets but I get a connectionClosedOK after the first request. Tried a few suggestions but can't really figure out how to fix it... as far as I understand the error happens on `res = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=10)`

The client code is here:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864604/websockets-exceptions-connectionclosedok-code-1000-ok-no-reason
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780416/websockets-in-fastapi-connectionclosedok-received-1000-ok


import time
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


async def ping(websocket):
    while True:
        await websocket.send('{"message":"PING"}')
        print('------ ping')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        
        
async def get_data(websocket, key):
        order = {'key' : key}
        json_data = json.dumps(order)
        await websocket.send(json_data)
        res = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=10)
        res = json.loads(res)
        return res


async def main():
    keeprunning = True
    i = 0
    #wss = websockets.serve(handle_request, "localhost", 8766)
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    #websocket = await websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval = None)
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri, timeout=15, ping_timeout=None, ping_interval=None):
        #task = asyncio.create_task(ping(websocket))
        while keeprunning and i < 10:
            i = i + 1
            print(f'counter {i}')
            res = await get_data(websocket, 'key')
            print(f"res: {res}")
            #time.sleep(5.0)
    print('main exit')
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

The server code is here:

```
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()



async def handle_request(websocket):
    message = await websocket.recv()
    data = json.loads(message)
    order = {'key' : data['key'], 'val1' : 1.0, 'val2' : 2.0 }
    json_data = json.dumps(order)
    await websocket.send(json_data)
    print("handle_request")


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handle_request, "localhost", 8765, ping_interval=None):
        print('world running...')
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever
    print('world done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: it seems `server` always closes connection after running `handle_request` - it is standard behavior. If you would run `client` without `while`-loop then `for websocket` would automatically reconnect and all would without problem. Or you have to run `while`-lloop inside `handle_request` and it should keep connection alive.

Comment: @MichaelButscher OK, I delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `server` closes connection after running `handler` - and it is normal behavior.

If `client` would use `for websocket` without `while`-loop then it would automatically create new connection and all would work OK.

```
async def main():
    i = 0
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri, timeout=15, ping_timeout=None, ping_interval=None):
        if i < 10:
            i = i + 1
            print(f'counter {i}')
            res = await get_data(websocket, 'key')
            print(f"res: {res}")
            time.sleep(3)  # slow down for tests
         else:
            break

    print('main exit')
```

It will need some `try/except` to catch error `GeneratorExit` when it exits `for websocket`-loop

---

But if you really want to keep connection then `server` would have to use `while`-loop in `handler` - to keep it running.

```
async def handle_request(websocket):

    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        #print('recv:', message)
        data = json.loads(message)

        order = {'key' : data['key'], 'val1' : 1.0, 'val2' : 2.0 }
        json_data = json.dumps(order)
        #print('send:', message)
        await websocket.send(json_data)
    
    print("handle_request")
```

You may see `while True` in `handler` in documentation for [Bootstrap the server](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/tutorial1.html#bootstrap-the-server)

It may need to use some message to inform `server` that `client` finishs connection.
Or you can use `try/except` like in documentation

```
async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await websocket.recv()
        except websockets.ConnectionClosedOK:
            break
        print(message)
```

And `client` needs some method to exit `for websocket` - because it raise error `GeneratorExit`

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was counterintuitive to me that a connection would close without me handling as I would assume it would be slowing the thing down to have to reopen the connection every time i want to send a message...