Character AI API closes connection when it shouldn't
I've tried breeding speech recognition and character.AI (because it has nice free api). When I try to send a message the connection suddenly drops.
I've tested "Simple Example" from github.com/kramcat/CharacterAI and it works.
Here's the code:
async def main():
    char = "ai token"
    client = aiocai.Client('token')
    me = await client.get_me()
    async with await client.connect() as chat:
        new, answer = await chat.new_chat(char, me.id)
    speak(answer.text)
    
    while True:
        
        if os.path.exists("recorded_speech.wav"):
            os.remove("recorded_speech.wav")
        text = record()
        print(text)
        
        message = await chat.send_message(char, new.chat_id, text)
        speak(f'{message.text}')
asyncio.run(main())

speak() is just a SAM tts. It works fine.
record() is simple stt, it works too.
text contains string with recorded voice
But when I get to message = await chat.send_message(char, new.chat_id, text) it gives me this exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python\tts\brain.py", line 97, in <module>
    print(asyncio.run(main()))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python\tts\brain.py", line 93, in main
    message = await chat.send_message(char, new.chat_id, text)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\characterai\aiocai\methods\chat2.py", line 360, in send_message
    await self.ws.send(json.dumps(message))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 628, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 929, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: sent 1000 (OK); then received 1000 (OK)

basically, it has to write CAI response into message and then voice it with SAM.
in fact I didn't change "Simple Example" code at all, just swapped out text = input('YOU: ') for simple voice recognition.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802323/2834978

The connection might be timing out if there's too much delay between requests. You could add a mechanism to send pings.
